# Adding network peering from MongoDB Atlas to Azure - Terraform

Tags: mongodb, azure, terraform

I'm trying to add a network peering from my mongoDB Atlas, which is an azure marketplace offer, to my Azure environment.
I'm using following code for this:

```
resource "mongodbatlas_network_peering" "peering" {
  project_id            = mongodbatlas_project.project.id
  container_id          = mongodbatlas_cluster.cluster.container_id
  provider_name         = "AZURE"
  azure_directory_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  azure_subscription_id = data.azurerm_subscription.subscription.id
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.resource_group_name
  vnet_name             = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  depends_on = [ azurerm_role_assignment.mongodb_role_assignment ]
}
```

But this is giving me following error:

```
error creating MongoDB Network Peering Connection: POST https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/peers: 404 (request "AZURE_CUSTOMER_NETWORK_UNREACHABLE") External Azure subscription unreachable.
```

The azure SPN that is running the Terraform code is contributor on the subscription, and network contributor on the vnet.
For now there's no firewall blocking the vnet.

Does the SPN need to become a user in the mongoDB or something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

how are you???

So, i had some problems to configure peering too. I'll send here each problem and solution. See if any thing can help you:

1 - We don't need to create a AppRegistraion. To bind the ServicePrincipal, you should use the MongoDb AppId:

Documentation:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/atlas-operator/ak8so-network-peering/

[image]

2 - You need to create three components to bind your VNet:

- ServicePrincipal
  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/2.6.0/docs/resources/service_principal
- RoleDefinition https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/2.79.1/docs/resources/role_definition
- RoleAssignment
  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/2.79.1/docs/resources/role_assignment

[image]

3 - To Configure the CIDR you should use outsides Ip Ranges. You can't to use one CIDR from your VNet. For example:

- You have the CIDR 10.20.0.0. Can use any public IP (192.168.20.0) justo to lock the traffic.

I wish this tips can help you. Good luck by!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it the other way around, by adding the web app ip to the accessable ip list of the mongodb.